# How to disable Mac Preview blurring / smoothing images in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, preview

I scanned a paper document to a PDF. Each page of the PDF is an image of a paper page. When I view the PDF in Mac's Preview app and zoom in, Preview blurs / smooths the image. When I view the PDF in Adobe Reader, it displays the actual pixels, which is what I want:

[image: Adobe Reader vs Mac Preview]

**How can I configure Preview to not blur / smooth images in PDFs?**

Here is a [related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143347/how-to-disable-antialiasing-smoothing-in-preview-for-images) post.

I have already tried the terminal command

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview PVPDFAntiAliasOption 0
```

and restarted Preview, and looked for other smoothing-related options for Preview using

```
defaults read com.apple.Preview
```